# how to use None vector3 value type in cpp?

Tags: c++

I use a Vector3 class to represent my actor position, but I need some value to indicate the position value is not set, (0,0,0) is a valid value, because the actor can be there.
One possible can be a larger value, like (9999999,9999999,999999) to indicate this special None value, but's is ugly.
Another possible may be use pointer instead of value.
But I want to hear some suggestions from you.

Comment: How about [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)?

Comment: I'd suggest `std::optional<Vector3>` too, but if you want to keep returning proper `Vector3` objects then `struct Vector3 { static const Vector3 None; int x,y,z; }; const Vector3 Vector3::None {INT_MAX, INT_MAX, INT_MAX};` could be an option too, why not.

Comment: You can use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` as an 'invalid' value. In case of `double` type I'd use `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`.

Comment: Why allow an actor without a position?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  The Actor receive pos from server, at initial, is has not received msg from server

Comment: @churill  When I google it, it seems like what I need, Thanks

Comment: One way to avoid it is to wait until all data is received from the server and only then create an actor object. std::optional will also work but IMHO it is less clean. What do you do if someone requests the position from an actor, and there is no position? You will need to handle each such case.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely don't think that my solutions are the best solutions, but here are two ways:

**1.) Don't allow the coordinates to remain uninitialized.**

This is relatively simple to implement - just create your own constructor with 3 parameters.

```
class Vector3{
    double x, y, z;
public:

    Vector3(double x, double y, double z): x(x), y(y), z(z){}

};
```

**2.) Use exceptions.**

A second solution could be that you allow a default constructor with no parameters, but use a hidden attribute called to indicate whether the coordinates have been set or not.
One way of implementing this is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Vector3{
    bool _set;
    double x, y, z;
public:
    Vector3(){ _set = false; }

    Vector3(double x, double y, double z){
        x = x; y = y; z = z; _set = true;
    }

    double get_x(){
        if (!_set) throw std::logic_error("Vector3 not initialized!\n");
        return x;
    }

    void set_x(double x){
        x = x; _set = true; 
    }
};
```

Obviously I've only written the sets and gets for the x coordinate, but you get the point. This way, if somebody attempts to read the coordinates of an uninitialized Vector3, an exception will be thrown. You can then process the exception in a catch block and decide how to act:

```
int main(){
try{
    // this works
    auto v1 = Vector3();
    v1.set_x(1);
    std::cout << v1.get_x() << std::endl;
    
    // this will throw an exception
    auto v2 = Vector3();
    std::cout << v2.get_x() << std::endl;
}
catch(std::logic_error e){
    // decide what to do here
    std::cout << e.what();
}
return 0;
```

}